# HTML5 canvas game Player movement

Tags: html, canvas

Im looking into making a game with HTML5 canvas. Does anyone know any good sites or tutorials on how to make a player move around the screen with the arrow keys? I cant seem to find a decent tutorial on how to handle the key events?

Comment: Your question is rather subjective, as you are asking for a "good" tutorial. Furthermore you don't show what you have tried or where you have looked. So it is also very open-ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is pretty good:

http://impactjs.com/documentation/animations

the ideas of how to do animation are there.

for keybaoard events:

http://html5.litten.com/moving-shapes-on-the-html5-canvas-with-the-keyboard/

Comment: I guess this will help. Thanks for the awnser